# when increasing UISlider value after a certain value crashes app libc++abi.dylib

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uislider, iso

I am setting ISO value from slider but after a certain value it crashes my app with libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException 
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the image is of no help. What does the crash log say?

Comment: @iOSer it says libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Thats not the complete log I feel. Can you copy paste the log?

Comment: Make sure you have set All Exceptions Breakpoint. Then when the crash occurs   enter on the debug console:  po $arg1 to print the exception information and then enter Thread.callStackSymbols to print the full stacktrace. Then update your question with the information above, in order to have the info needed to help you

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624649-iso says that "Only ISO values between minISO and maxISO are supported" maybe you're setting the ISO value higher than allowed. Suggestion would be to figure out the minISO and maxISO values first and then set them as minimum and maximum values of the slider

Comment: @iOSer hey m setting max value 1600 which is allowed

Comment: @ChristosKoninis okay let me do that

Comment: @ChristosKoninis how to get crash log , can u help me in that

Comment: Behind that, in the console where there are output in bold, show what you've got. Copy/paste it, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Behind that I got exception name only